# PC Virus says: "It's a trap!"

Tags: internet, browser, virus

recently everywhere I go online I will find little snippets of text replaced with

```
"It's a Trap!"
```

It seemed to start with yahoo.com, but it has expanded to biblegateway, google, and much more! I don't know why its doing this, what type of virus remover to get, or what to do in general. Anyone else having this problem? Thanks!

Comment: If it's just inside your web browser you should try disabling any add-ons or plugins. Try installing a different web browser if you don't already have one.

Comment: For virus cleanup instructions check out the answers here: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: Time to nuke from orbit and reinstall your os

Comment: Restart and update the firmware your internet router. There are malicious images out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally recommend as a first step removing your web browser and reinstalling it.

**If you use Chrome, Opera, Firefox, or any other web browser that does *not* come with your OS**, then use [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)
to remove your browser and make sure there are no leftover files. After that, re-download your browser from [Ninite](https://ninite.com), and then go to the botttom paragraph.

**If you use Internet Explorer**, open Programs and Features, hit 
"Turn Windows Features On or Off", and uncheck Internet Explorer 11. Reboot and then do the steps again, but this time check the box instead of unchecking it. Go to the bottom paragraph.

**If you use Microsoft Edge,** just skip to the next paragraph.

Next, run an antivirus scan. Open the start menu, and search for "mrt". Hit Enter. Select "Full Scan", the click Next. It may take a loooong time to complete. Even if that comes up clean, try a scan with your favorite antivirus. If that comes up clean, then you probably have removed the virus.
Open your web browser and try a webpage. If that doesn't work, then you have a more complicated virus.

Comment: A plugin was messed up and doing things in the background. TNX